# bash get second occurence after split

Tags: command-line, text-processing

I want to split the text volumes with "|" as space and get the second occurence ie; value - 'test2'

```
volumes=|test1|test2
echo $volumes | tr "|" "\n"
```

The above command splits into each line..I can loop through it and get the value but want the most efficient way.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the shell's built in parameter substitution `"${volumes##*|}"` which removes the longest initial string matching up to a `|` character

```
$ volumes="|test1|test2"
$ echo "${volumes##*|}"
test2
```

Alternatively, there is `cut`

```
$ cut -d\| -f3 <<< "$volumes"
test2
```

or `awk`

```
$ awk -F\| '{print $NF}' <<< "$volumes"
test2
```

Answer (score 3):

Steeldriver already gave you the easiest options. Here are a few more:

- `awk`

  ```
  awk -F'|' '{print $3}' <<<"$volumes"
  ```
- `perl`

  ```
  perl -F"\|" -lane 'print $F[2]' <<<"$volumes"
  ```
- `sed`

  ```
  sed 's/.*|//' <<<$volumes
  ```

Comment: awk, perl, sed, and me? :D

Comment: [Tim Toady!](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/There's_more_than_one_way_to_do_it)

Comment: indeed, `td` works also

Answer (score 2):

With your `tr` command

```
$ volumes="|test1|test2"
$ tr "|" "\n" <<< $volumes | tail -n1
test2
```